# Ошибка при подключении к почтовому ящику

Tags: python, email

Пытаюсь подключиться к почте yandex при помощи скрипта

```
import imaplib, email

server = "imap.yandex.ru"
port = "993"
login = "login"
password = "pass"

box = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server, port)
box.login(login, password)
box.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')

for num in data[0].split() :
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print 'Message %sn%sn' % (num, data[0][1])

box.close()
box.logout()
```

Но возникает ошибка

`maplib.error: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] LOGIN LOGIN Invalid credentials or IMAP is disabled`

Аналогичная ситуация и при использовании POP3.

Аутентификационные данные введены правильно.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: У меня на яндекс этот код вполне входит

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том, что на почтовом сервере был запрещен доступ по IMAP

Answer (score 2):

по этой ссылке настройка, нужно разрешить
 https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это ссылка непосредственно на настройку, которую нужно поменять, а не просто внешний источник.